# How can I prevent return to login screen when entering extended characters using onboard in 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I recently upgraded ubuntu to 18.04 and very gradually getting ground teething problems. One very important need I have is to be able quickly and easily select extended characters while working in libreoffice documents. In 16.10 I used onboard, which had some little quirks but was generally superb for this purpose. I was dismayed to find that it has been replaced by  woefully inadequate onscreen keyboard that not only disconcertingly appears and disappears (like the wretched vanishing scrollbars in nautilus) but also in no way seems up to the task - a very distinctive step backwards. So I installed onboard (as Joshua - I think - helpfully suggested in another thread. However this is now giving problems. I can enter the basic characters from any of my chosen languages without problem, but when I try to obtain an extended character, e.g. iota with acute accent (classical greek) or 'a' with macron (english, used e.g. in writing latin grammars) I long-click on the basic onboard character (iota/a respectively) which brings up a 'menu' of extended characters. But when I try to enter one of these characters I am immediately logged out and returned to the login screen (there is no restart/reboot, just logout).
How can I fix this, or is there a better alternative to onboard which I can install?
Thanks
/Gary

Comment: I'm running Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (installed and up to date). I tried all the 'a alternatives' after long clicking, and they work (with `onboard`). There is a minor glitch: the first time I select an alternative character nothing happens, but after that I can get all the available alternatives printed on the screen (in LibreOffice as well as in a terminal window).

Comment: Thats what I found in 16.10. It has been causing problems for me in 18.04 as I said, but if its working for you there's obviously nothing wrong with the package per se. Perhaps I'll try to uninstall / reinstall and see if it works for me then.

Comment: If you still have problems with standard Ubuntu, but it works for me with Lubuntu, the problem may be with Ubuntu's desktop environment. You can try `onboard` in live sessions of Ubuntu, Lubuntu and maybe some other flavour (in the Ubuntu family). Do not install, try live (booted from a USB pendrive).